# Angular set mat-input to error state after http error response

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-form-field, mat-input

is there a possibility to set mat-input in error state after http error response? On submit of form from code below im sending an http request and i would like to show the mat-error but it shows only when input is in error state and i don't know how to set it "manualy" after error response

```html
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="placeholder" formControlName="Input" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="variable">error message</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**serviceClass:**

```
export class serviceClass{
    private url: string = 'your url'// your http request url

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    callApi() {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }
}
```

**componentClass:** while subscribing http request if you get error in response can set the `errorVariable` true.

```
export class componentClass{
        private url: string = 'your url'
        public errorVariable:boolean;
        constructor(private service: serviceClass) { }

        getApi() {
            return this.service.callApi().subscribe(
              (response:string)=>{
                console.log(response);
             },
            (error)=>{
                console.error(error);
                this.errorVariable=true;
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

**htmlTemplate:**

```
<mat-error *ngIf="errorVariable">error message</mat-error>
```

Comment: this wont work. 
To show <mat-error> below input not only the ngIf needs to be true but also the input field needs to be in error state.

Comment: try `this.exampleForm.get('Input').setErrors({valid:false});` in place of `this.errorVariable=true;` and let me know if it works.